# How to know app open from notification or app icon click android?

Tags: android, notifications, splash-screen

Actually i want to know app is open from notification click or open from app icon click, i pass some parameter from notification click like.

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SplashScreen.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("IS_FROM_NOTIFICATION", Utility.NOTI_TYPE_VERSE);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("firebase_node_name", Utility.FIREBASE_AFTERNOON_BIBLE_VERSE_NOTE);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("title", context.getResources().getString(R.string.menuAfternoonVerse));
```

and this data get in Splash screen and pass it to the respected activity, and open this activity, when i back press close the app, now app is in background state, when i resume app from background it will show notification activity,

Comment: What's the problem you want to show other activity rather than notification activity when coming from background?

Comment: Problem is open notification activity after click on notification, and then close app and open from recent app it will open notification activity this is not happen

Comment: actually when i open from recent app it will open my default activity, not open notification activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check:

```
if (!wasLaunchedFromRecents() && (myIntentData.getStringExtra("IS_FROM_NOTIFICATION").equals(Utility.NOTI_TYPE_1))) {
        // from notification
    }

private fun wasLaunchedFromRecents(): Boolean {
    return getIntent().flags and Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY === Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY
}
```

Comment: i already try this but when i get back from recent app i also get the IS_FROM_NOTIFICATION value

Comment: Does it have value?

Comment: yes i define in my question the pass value, and i also get the value back from recent app,

Comment: Only app icon click to launch app i can't get the value

Comment: When get value , you remove getIntent().removeExtra("IS_FROM_NOTIFICATION ")

Comment: can u tell me when i remove this extra value "IS_FROM_NOTIFICATION "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190352/discussion-between-gaurav-mandlik-and-cng-nguyn).

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
intent.putExtra("IS_FROM_NOTIFICATION", Utility.NOTI_TYPE_VERSE);
intent.putExtra("firebase_node_name", Utility.FIREBASE_AFTERNOON_BIBLE_VERSE_NOTE);
intent.putExtra("title", context.getResources().getString(R.string.menuAfternoonVerse));

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notificationId + 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder1 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "my_channel_01").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name)).setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("title")).setContentIntent(pendingIntent1);

mBuilder1.setAutoCancel(true);

  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
         mBuilder1.setChannelId("my_channel_01");

         CharSequence name = "My New Channel";                   // The user-visible name of the channel.
         int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

         NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("my_channel_01", name, importance); //Create Notification Channel
         mNotificationManager1.createNotificationChannel(channel);
  }
  mNotificationManager1.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), mBuilder1.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all when you send data in intent to splash screen add Flags to intent like below

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SplashScreen.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("IS_FROM_NOTIFICATION", Utility.NOTI_TYPE_VERSE);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("firebase_node_name", Utility.FIREBASE_AFTERNOON_BIBLE_VERSE_NOTE);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("title", context.getResources().getString(R.string.menuAfternoonVerse));
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Then in notification activity onBackPressed don't call finish()